# How to remove first comma when pushing inside input value with split(',')?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with split() function, I have input in which I push ids that I'm getting through mapping objects.

**My HTML:**

```
<input class="custom-img-id" name="custom-img-id" type="hidden" value="" />
```

**My JS:**

```
frame.on( 'select', function() {
  var imgIdInput = $( '.custom-img-id' );

  var attachments = frame.state().get('selection').map(function( a ) {
    a.toJSON();
    return a;
  }),
  thesamepicture = false,
  i;

  for (i = 0; i < attachments.length; ++i) {
      imgContainer.append('<img src="' + attachments[i].attributes.url + '"/>');
      
      imgIdInput.val().split(",").push( attachments[i].id );
  }
  imgIdInput.val( imgIdInput.val().split(",").join() );
});
```

If for example I have two object with ids 100 and 101, I will get inside input value this:

```
value=",100,101"
```

How to remove first comma? I think I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I'd suggest fixing the logic which creates the array with empty items instead of hacking the solution to remove leading `,` characters. At first glance it seems that using `split()` and `push()` in every iteration of your `for` loop is a code smell, not least because you do nothing with the result. Can you add a working example to the question.

Comment: I don't see how you're getting IDs in it at all. Are they being added in code you haven't shown? This line doesn't do it: `imgIdInput.val().split(",").push( attachments[i].id );` That's effectively a long no-op, it creates an array (the result of split), pushes something to it, and then throws it away.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, it's not full code, I'm getting ids from variable attachments, as you can see I'm mapping through and getting objects with attributes as id, url and etc.

Comment: Couple of quick alternatives: `",100,101".replace(",", " ").trim().split(" ").join(",")` or `",100,101".replace(",", " ").trim().replace(" ", ",")` (given the assumption that IDs don't have spaces or commas) - but agree that fixing the code so this doesn't happen is a better approach (so an XY problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is probably that `"".split(",")` gives you `[""]`, not an empty array.

I'd suggest splitting the string once prior to the loop (handling the issue with `""`), adding to the resulting array, and then converting it back to a string once at the end, see `***` comments:

```
frame.on( 'select', function() {
  var imgIdInput = $( '.custom-img-id' );

  var attachments = frame.state().get('selection').map(function( a ) {
    a.toJSON();
    return a;
  }),
  thesamepicture = false,
  i;

  // *** Get the current IDs as an array
  var val = imgIdInput.val().trim();
  var ids = val ? imgIdInput.val().split(",") : [];
  for (i = 0; i < attachments.length; ++i) {
      imgContainer.append('<img src="' + attachments[i].attributes.url + '"/>');
      
      // *** Add to the array
      ids.push(attachments[i].id);
  }
  // *** Save the IDs in the hidden input
  imgIdInput.val(ids.join());
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now everything is working and I got the point what you did.

Answer (score 0):

you can use replace

```
imgIdInput.val( imgIdInput.val().split(",").join().replace(",","") );


console.log(",100,101".replace(",",""))  // "100,101"
```

Comment: While this works for the solution outlined in the OP, it's *really* not a good idea. What happens if there's no leading `,` in the output - as there should not be. In that case the first two items get merged

Comment: And while you could tweak it to just remove a leading `,`, this is putting tape over the crack rather than fixing the glass. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use split, filter and join function of the array & String to get the expected output.

```js
var value=",100,101"

value = value.split(",")

const finalValue = value.filter(tmp =>{
return tmp !== ''
})

console.log(finalValue.join(","));
```